# Testing vectors and nested vectors in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

Is there a way in Clojure to test a vector and see if it's nested, i.e. a way to test [:a :b :c :d] vs. [[:a :b] [:c :d]]?

I've tried the test

```
(vector? [:a :b :c :d])
 true
```

but it remains true for nested vectors as well,

```
(vector? [[:a :b] [:c :d]])
 true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking if any of them are sequential seems close:

```
user> (every? #(not (sequential? %)) [:a :b :c :d])
true
user> (every? #(not (sequential? %)) [:a :b :c :d [:e]])
false
```

because all the base collections can be made into sequences, though it may be necessary to also check for Java arrays:

```
(every? #(not (sequential? %)) [:a :b :c :d (into-array [1 2 3])])
```

Comment: `(every? #(not (f %)) coll)` should really be `(not-any? f coll)`.

Comment: @Arthur This is partially related as I have used the code you wrote above. Is there a clear way to iterate the code segment after `:else`? The goal is to be able to drill n levels deep into a collection.                                                     `(defn test-func [x f]
 (cond 
   (every? #(not (sequential? %)) x) (apply f x) 
  :else (map #(apply f %) x)))`

Answer (score 0):

`vector?` returns `true` if its argument is a vector (implements `IPersistentVector`).  `[:a :b :c :d]` is a vector.  So is `[[:a :b] [:c :d]]`.  Therefore, calling `vector?` on either of them will return `true`.

Now, we can say a vector is nested if any of its *elements* is a vector.  We can test for this using `some` and the `vector?` predicate:

```
(defn nested-vector? [v]
  (some vector? v))
```

This will test specifically for vectors.  However, you might want to take a more general approach that applies to any `Sequential` data structure:

```
(defn nested? [coll]
  (some sequential? coll))
```